# Decentralization of business due to internet/mass communication, or mere bosses-at-a-distance?

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, unemployment

Excuse my question if it sounds brutish and uneducated but I'm curious about the recent trend of businesses like Uber, Google Play Store, Apple Store, possibly even Craigslist (et al) which are more of a platform to offer your services/wares versus the "traditional" large-corporate employers (e.g. Macy's) which employ you multiple days and provide benefits and whatnot.
My question is multi-faceted so I will ask first:

**Is there a paper or are there papers that talk about this trend and its implications? Or am I seeing something that is irrelevant to a change in markets/employment/the way we typically do business?**

And, if indeed it is merely (as in the title) "bosses-at-a-distance" (that is, not face-to-face with you), does this bode well for people as even unskilled laborers can find menial employment, albeit without benefits and whatnot?
Moreoever, is this "decentralization" in any sense of the word? And, if it is, how does it bode for the future? Will odd-jobs be the daily endeavors of the 22nd century human?
Thank you for putting up with my ignorance!

Comment: Which facet of those implications are you looking for? There may be many of them, and that would make your question very broad.